# Reading from a file a line that has commas and spaces in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, file, parsing

I'm reading from a file that has a line which has a pair of number separated by commas:

```
1 2, 2 3, 3 1, 4 1, 2 4, S
```

With the result being:

```
ValueOne - 1 -- ValueTwo - 2 
ValueOne - 2 -- ValueTwo - 3 
ValueOne - 3 -- ValueTwo - 1 
ValueOne - 4 -- ValueTwo - 1
ValueOne - 2 -- ValueTwo - 4
Break
```

This is my current code:

```
try{
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("graph.txt"));
        while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
            String value = scanner.next();
            String[] values = value.split(" |,");
            if(value.equals("S")){
                System.out.println("Break");
                break;
            }
            int v1 = Integer.parseInt(values[0]);
            int v2 = Integer.parseInt(values[1]);
            System.out.println("ValueOne - " + v1 + " -- " + "ValueTwo - "+ v2);
        }
        scanner.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I'm getting an **ArrayIndexOutOFBoundsException** at "int v2 = Integer.parseInt(values[1]);"

I'm sure I'm missing something silly, but I just need some fresh eyes to take a look at it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't splitting the string properly. You need to do:

```
 String[] values = value.split(",");
```

But even then you won't get the expected output. That will split the values into pairs. You will have to then spit again like so:

```
for(String value : values){
   String[] pairs = value.split(" "); 
    int v1 = Integer.parseInt(pairs[0]);
    int v2 = Integer.parseInt(pairs[1]);
    System.out.println("ValueOne - " + v1 + " -- " + "ValueTwo - "+ v2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String value = scanner.next();
```

This is only getting the first token from your file. You need to replace it with the following so you can read the whole line:

```
String value = scanner.nextLine();
```

Also, you need to do 2 separate splits. One split on a comma, such that you have the elements [1 2],[2 3] etc., and another split on your space so you can then reference each value specifically and print them out as required.

Answer (score 0):

Your `scanner.next()` reads only one token  at a time (till space), so you can't use `split(",")` directly, rather you need to write logic as shown in the below code with comments:

```
String v1 = null;
String v2 = null;
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("graph.txt"));
while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
       String value = scanner.next();
       if(value.equals("S")){
            System.out.println("Break");
             break;
      }

     //Check if token ends with ','
     if(value.endsWith(",")) {
            v1 = v2;//swap v1 and v2
            v2 = value.substring(0, value.length());//substring till ','

            //Since ',' one pair consumed, so print the values
            System.out.println("ValueOne - " + v1 + " -- " + "ValueTwo - "+ v2);
      } else {

          //If token does not end with ',' just consume value, don't print
          v2 = value;
      }
}
```